# Negative $r$ in polar coordinate while integrating

Tags: calculus, integration, polar-coordinates

The question asks $\iint_R (3x+4y^2)\; dA$ where $R$ is the region in the upper half plane bounded by the circles $x^2+y^2=1$ and $x^2+y^2=4$
$$\int_0^\pi \int_1^2 (3r\cos \theta + 3r^2 \sin^2 \theta) r \;dr d\theta $$
Now the question is since $r=-1$ is the same as $r=1$ by the convention if we replace the bounds of $r$ by $-1,-2$ or $-1,2$ it will give a different answer! What's wrong here?

In the past the first time I learned about $r$ in polar coordinate we did not allowed negative values why in the books like Calculus Early Transcendentals by James Stewart have this convention?

In complex analysis $r$ is equal to $|z|$ which always positive.

Comment: The expression  $$(3r\cos\theta+3r^2\sin^2\theta)r$$ you are integrating over is not invariant under the map $r\longmapsto -r$, so there's no reason why the integral should stay the same.

Comment: Yeah thats correct but why they have this convention. I mean r=1 is the same circle as r=-1 by their convention! my argument is we should not accept the convention at the beginning we do not need it.

Comment: related to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/964980/in-polar-coordinates-can-r-be-negative

Comment: related to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2503564/limits-of-integration-in-polar-coordinates

Comment: I figured it out, check the second link Eric Tower answer